# Functions doesn't work when called by timeOut-function, but works alone with 'onclick'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried to create some code which gives visitors the possibility to make a draft of an email and save it, in case they are leaving the contact-page to look for further information before sending it. I've succeeded with this by letting the visitor manually save a cookie with the draft. However, i wish to make it more automatic, and in this regard I found a very nice code and demo in, here which did that every second. The original code can be found on the link, and my adjusted code can be seen below: http://jsfiddle.net/madlittlemods/nxq4a/

```
var timeoutId;
$('#email_1, #subject_1, #message_1').on('input propertychange change', function() {
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
        // Runs 1 second (1000 ms) after the last change    
        setCookie(name, value);
        storeValues(form);
        alert("Alert was run.");
    }, 1000);
});
```

Therefore I used the "timeout" part of this demo to try and run my cookie-saving function every time the user stopped changing the textarea. However the functions isn't executed, and i simply just can't figure out why. As you can see I have tried to insert an alert to see if the "setTimeout" function was run, and the alert only runs if i remove the "storeValues" function, as well as removing the parameters from the "setCookie(name, value)" function.

Therefore I hope that some of you guys in here can help me. I must admit that i'm not very familiar with JavaScript, and basically all of the code is some that I have found on the internet, borrowed and adjusted to my own website. This also means that it might as well be a little, stupid error, which I just can't seem to find. Please note that all of the remaining code works as intentioned, and the problem (from my view) only seems to be with the code mentioned above.

First of all a full demo can be found here: http://codepen.io/Chris7/pen/oLNBbx

Just so that you won't have to follow the demo, the functions for setCookie and storeValues comes here:

setCookie:

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
}
```

storeValues:

```
function storeValues(form)  {
    setCookie("email_1", form.email_1.value);
    setCookie("subject_1", form.subject_1.value);
    setCookie("message_1", form.message_1.value);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining `name`, `value`, and `form` when you call the functions?

Comment: Please add your adjusted code in your question directly in a snippet code within the editor.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan to be honest i don't that i am anywhere - i've used the codes from these guys as inspiration http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/ (i couldn't insert more than 2 links in the original post). As the script worked I thought that it wasn't necessary, nor do I know what I should define them as. Sorry for my lack of knowledge :)

 and to LoicTheAztec do you mean the entire code from the demo, or?

Comment: Well it actually seems that I might have fixed it. After your comment @RoryMcCrossan I went over the code again (for the 50th time or so) and tried to remove some of the parameters, and ended up changing the storeValues(form) by using document.getElementById to fetch the textareas instead. Furthmore I added the parameters "name, value" to the timeout function, and now it actually works (including setting the cookie).

To be honest I have no idea why it works now, but thank you for the prompt reply. Should i set anything to an answer? Demo here: http://codepen.io/Chris7/pen/rLaBQZ